# チャット読み込み中の個所が英語のままです

Tags: バグ, 仕様, 英語

[image: loading *ルーム名* Just a second...]
これは少々お待ちください、という意味でしょうね。

Comment: チャットはStackExchangeネットワーク全体で共通のシステムになっていて、表示言語の切り替えなどもサポートされていません。なのでそのメッセージ以外にも英語だらけですが、このサイト本体のようには翻訳できないのが現状です。

Answer (score 2):

コメントでunaristさんがおっしゃるとおり、chatはネットワーク全体で同じシステムになっています。ですので、翻訳は**出来ない**のが現状です。<sup>勿論、Transifexでも管理されていません。</sup>
多言語対応はもう少し先になると思います。

Comment: なるほど、これは今のところ仕様という事ですね。

Comment: @Laclip 将来に翻訳するかもしれませんが、多言語ユーザーがお大幅増やさない限り優先度が低いです。